# Wildfly10 Throws an error while deploying an Oauth server's war file

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, wildfly-10

[image]

> I am getting this error while deploying an Oauth Server on wildfly10.
>   Do I need to change **Application.prperties** file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you are deploying an OAuth server It has application.properties
>   You can check for the application.yml of other services on your wildfly10.
>   There should not be any spaces in application.yml

Comment: Yes. Thank you. There was a mistake in application.yml file of discovery server which i have deployed before Oauth server.